# Correct architecture when accessing data from many different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture

I am working on a Android app which have 5 fragments and some java classes. 
I have to be able to read and edit an arraylist containing pojo's from across these fragments and classes. For example updating from the internet and then updating recyclerView in one of the fragments or sorting the objects in a recyclerView in one fragment and have those changes updated in the recyclerView in another fragment.

I have been looking at notifyDatasetChanged, but cannot get it right, when starting an update in the background and then wants it to update onSucceed in the active fragment.

I have been looking on RxJava with the Arraylist as observable, but once again I ran into problems when I wanted to subscribe from multiple fragments.

And of course I did a arraylist in a singleton, but I am pretty sure that is bad coding :-)

Comment: Post some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the data that is going to be accessed by all of the fragments in a Service. Each Fragment can bind to the service to retrieve a reference to the data and to register a listener (you will have to make a custom one to handle the events that you are interested in) that will tell each Fragment to update its own view. Each Fragment would implement its own Adapter that would wrap the shared data that lives in the Service.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I wanted to do it before I accepted :-)